# When does Potential start working?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

The ability "Potential" says it activates at a certain percentage, but is it stated anywhere what this percentage is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Kiranico](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/armor/skill/potential) all levels of potential (Adrenaline+1, Adrenaline+2 and Worrywort) become active when health drops below 40% of maximum (150).

Comment: You might want to clarify whether that's 40% of the base 100 HP or 40% of your maximum 150 HP (i.e., after eating a max potion)